# Apache POI usage with Apache Felix

Tags: apache-poi, maven-3, apache-felix, osgi-bundle, atlassian-plugin-sdk

I'm trying to import Apache POI to Atlassian Jira Plugin for reading excel files.

At the beginning, I started with adding just

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>${poi.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
        <version>${poi.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>${poi.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

poi.version is 3.14

then when I started the plugin it gave

```
Unresolved constraint in bundle com.tezExtensions [165]: Unable to resolve 165.0: missing requirement [165.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=com.sun.javadoc)
```

Then I edited pom with some instructions which I found on another StackOverflow question [Pax Exam issue with Apache POI wrapped bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34072711/pax-exam-issue-with-apache-poi-wrapped-bundle)

```
 <instructions>
                    <Atlassian-Plugin-Key>${atlassian.plugin.key}</Atlassian-Plugin-Key>
                    <!-- Add package to export here -->
                    <Export-Package>com.sony.poc.api,</Export-Package>
                    <_exportcontents>
                        org.apache.poi.*;version=${poi.version},
                        org.openxmlformats.schemas.*;version=${poi.schema.version},
                        schemasMicrosoftComOfficeExcel.*;version=${poi.schema.version},
                        schemasMicrosoftComOfficeOffice.*;version=${poi.schema.version},
                        schemasMicrosoftComOfficePowerpoint.*;version=${poi.schema.version},
                        schemasMicrosoftComVml.*;version=${poi.schema.version},
                        org.etsi.uri.*;version=${poi.security.version}
                    </_exportcontents>
                    <!-- Add package import here -->
                    <Import-Package>
                        com.sun.javadoc;resolution:=optional,
                        com.sun.tools.javadoc;resolution:=optional,
                        org.apache.crimson.jaxp;resolution:=optional,
                        org.apache.tools.ant;resolution:=optional,
                        org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs;resolution:=optional,
                        org.apache.tools.ant.types;resolution:=optional,
                        junit.framework.*;resolution:=optional,
                        junit.textui.*;resolution:=optional,
                        org.junit.*;resolution:=optional,
                        org.apache.xml.security.*;resolution:=optional,
                        org.apache.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.*;resolution:=optional,
                        org.springframework.osgi.*;resolution:="optional", org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.*;resolution:="optional", *</Import-Package>
                    <DynamicImport-Package>
                        org.apache.xmlbeans.*,
                        schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans.*
                    </DynamicImport-Package>
```

With this configuration, I get this error;

```
Unable to resolve 165.0: missing requirement [165.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.xml.resolver)
```

Is there anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution.

I have added these as dependency

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>${poi.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
        <version>${poi.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>${poi.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>stax</groupId>
                <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
        <artifactId>woodstox-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

And also added these are to inside of Import-Package tag

```
*;resolution:=optional, com.ctc.wstx.stax.*
```

That's all.

Comment: Hi Omer,
I am using Service Mix and trying to read the xlsx using POI, but I am getting the following error:
     **Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: 
     org.apache.xerces.stax.XMLEventFactoryImpl cannot be cast to 
     javax.xml.stream.XMLEventFactory
    at  javax.xml.stream. 
    XMLEventFactory.newInstance(XMLEventFactory.java:
    30) at  org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.marshallers.
    PackagePropertiesMarshaller.<clinit>
   (PackagePropertiesMarshaller.java:41)**      
However. when I create a separate java project and read xlsx, it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Hi Umer, I don't have an experience with Service Mix and I can not say anything without seeing your implementation. If you can open a new question for your problem, I think someone gonna help you. Good luck!

Comment: This might be old, but this solved my problem!
Thanks!